# Preference category in cardview

Tags: android, material-design, preference

I have created a preference activity for my app, however I want to give it a Material/card look. I want each category to be in a card just like Android Lollipop settings app does. I have searched for a solution, however I couldn;t find any solution. Any pointers/help is very appreciated!

Best Regards